# replacing relative image src with absolute ones on joomla

Tags: joomla, relative-path, str-replace, absolute-path

I need to mail some html code stored in the database.

For the images to show as well, I need to replace the relative path with absolute ones.

I have a variable called $display, which holds the HTML.

to do it I try the fallowing:

```
$root=JURI::root();
 str_replace('src="/images', 'src="' . $root .'images', $display); 

var_dump($display);//for testing
```

$display seems to have not changed at all.

**update 1**

Ive' been advised to change the code to this:

```
$root=JURI::root();
$display = str_replace('src="/images', 'src="' . $root .'images', $display)
```

I have also tried

```
$display = str_replace('src="/images', 'src="' . $root .'images', $display);
```

But - both didnt work just yet :[

It changed

```
src="/images/joomla_black.gif"
```

to

```
src="http://images/joomla_black.gif"
```

without the full url :[

any advice?

**UPDATE 2**

added this:

```
echo('non fixed:');
var_dump($display);

$root=JURI::root();
$display = str_replace('src="/images', 'src="' . $root .'images', $display);
//fix images in display to absolute paths for mailing


echo('fixed:');
var_dump($display);
```

both display strings seem identical on the out put

Comment: what is output of `$root`?

Comment: var dump yields
string(24) "http://www.bigberta.com/"     This is the full domain of my test site. **the adress is WITH http://www** (it doesnt show  here)

Comment: and what shows `var_dump($display)` after you do `$display = str_replace('src="/images', 'src="' . $root .'images', $display);`? also, what is the difference in your update 1 between the two examples you tried, except the first one has a syntax error due to lack of `;` at the end?

Comment: see edit 2 - I added 2 dumps - before and after. both identical, it seems to me :[

Comment: can you show the content of `$var_dump($display)`?

Comment: currently it is
string(136) "
    <p>
      scoremin is 3
    <br></br><img width="225" height="50" border="0" style="border: 0;" alt="joomla black" src="/images/joomla_black.gif"></img></p>
      "

Comment: That code works for me, I get image with absolute url, so I don't know what else to say, except maybe you have an oversight in the code somewhere, or it works properly, but you are unaware of it :)

Comment: Maybe I will ask my host. I check now and it works localy. Thank you very much for your help. If u could repost your answer, I will rep you.

Comment: Did it, thanks, I hope you will resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_replace` will return value, it won't change the `$display` variable, so you need to do

`$display = str_replace('src="/images', 'src="' . $root .'images', $display);`

The other line you posted will return root domain in case joomla is in a subfolder, I don't think you need that

Comment: Hello Mrko.
I edit my main post with more info, Thanks for the help!

Comment: isn't in `$root` variable full domain name? and did you forget to assign `str_replace` return value to `$display` as I wrote you? I don't see in your updated code that you assigned return to `$display`